# How ask user to input only specific value in form like (2/4), (3/4) and such

Tags: python-3.x, cs50

I am completing my Harvard's cs50 python course.

There is problem I encountered in an assignment.

The assignment is related error handling (exceptions)
I have get input from user in form of 2/4 or 1/4 or anything
not string
Then have to convert it into percentage
I know that I can handle value error and zerodivisionerror

But my problem is what type of input I ask user and how to convert it in percentage

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Fraction: "))

    except ValueError:
        pass
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use regular expressions?

If you can use the regular expressions then you can try this:

```
import re

while True:
    fraction = input("Fraction (in the form x/y): ")
    if re.match(r'^\d+/\d+$', fraction):
        # Input is in the correct format, so we can proceed with conversion
        numerator, denominator = map(int, fraction.split('/'))
        percentage = numerator / denominator * 100
        print(f"{fraction} = {percentage:.2f}%")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a fraction in the form x/y.")
```

Without using Regex:

```
while True:
    fraction = input("Fraction (in the form x/y): ")
    if fraction.split("/") and len(fraction.split("/")) == 2:
        # Input is in the correct format, so we can proceed with conversion
        numerator, denominator = map(int, fraction.split('/'))
        percentage = numerator / denominator * 100
        print(f"{fraction} = {percentage:.2f}%")
        break
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Please enter a fraction in the form x/y.")
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, HiMesh. Thank you for your answer. But, In the course, I have not learned about regular expression yet. So, I think this assignment should be solved by without using regular expressions. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: You can use just the split function instead of regex.
In your case, replace if condition with this line:

`if fraction.split("/") and len(fraction.split("/")) == 2:`


@Sujit, I have updated the answer to use it without the regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to both match the `x/y` fraction notation, but also filter out either side being (starting with) a `0` as follows:

```
import re

while True:
    fraction = input("Enter a fraction: ")
    if (match := re.match(r'^([1-9]\d*)/([1-9]\d*)$', fraction)):
        print(int(match[1]) / int(match[2]) * 100)
    else:
        print("Invalid fraction.")
```